# how to create user defined table (table name is in a string ) in oracle using java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ddl

how to create user defined table (table name is in a string ) oracle using java

```
String Tablename="student";
stmt=con.prepareStatement("create table"+Tablename+"(name varchar(12),class varchar(12))");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

with out string i.e user defined table name it works fine:

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement("create table student (name varchar(12),class varchar(12))");
```

but the above listed versions which takes string as user name shows following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command
```

Answer (score 3):

Leave spaces before and after the table name, please.

Your original code resulted in this SQL command getting executed:

```
create tableMyTablename(name varchar(12),class varchar(12))
```

And in that, the `tableMyTablename` was not comprehensible for the DB...

Correctly:

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement("create table "+Tablename+" (name varchar(12),class varchar(12))");
```

Also, a few notes:

- Java naming: variable names start with *lowercase* letters
- this (preparing the statement) doesn't really make sense. It is not reusable to have a statement that can only create the same structure for a table.
- it is wise to avoid the + to concatenate Strings, and other objects' string representations... It may have very unexpected results, even compile errors...
- logging: in such situations, it is always wise to log the created SQL commands. Even a *(yuck!)* `System.out.println();` is better than nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Put a space after "create table" i.e.

```
"create table "
```

Your statement was being evaluated as create tablestudent...